# Scrapy Update a CSV with new info

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scrapy

I am **scraping** info of a game where you buy and sell players (bet). I would like to update a CSV file with **scraped** info about the final price. This information can only be completed 3 days after when some "figures" are sold (and some other are no). Then, with a second scrape I can get the new info and send it to a new CSV. But the ideal scenario is Scrapy to update somehow the current CSV with a new column, instead of having two separates files.

So far, I have tried with Pandas without success. The following code, read each "FigureID" and save the CSV each time. So at the end I only have one value in the Sell column.

Any brilliant idea here?

example CSV file

```
FigureId price date
442124   455   20/05/03
442156   645   20/05/03
442134   235   21/05/03
```

example Second CSV file

```
FigureId SellPrice 
442124   830   
442156   Nan
442134   565
```

In my code, I **scrape** the SellPrice and FigureId, then parse it with meta to a new function. But then, I don't update the SellPrice column properly (only the last value)// clearly I need to create the list of all elements... but I don't know how to do it.

This is my code so far

```
def parse_urls(self, response):
    
    try:
        dateSell_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@id="transHistory"]/table//tr[1]/td[1]/text()').extract_first()
        dateSell = re.sub(r'\s', '', dateSell_xpath)
        dateSold = datetime.strptime(dateSell, '%d-%m-%Y')
        Sold = (self.dateNow - dateSold).total_seconds()* 1.1574e-5

        if Sold < 3:
            price_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@id="transHistory"]/table//tr[1]/td[6]/text()').extract_first()
            priceSell = re.sub(r'\s', '', price_xpath)
            url = str(response.url)
            FigureId= str.split(url,"FigureId=")[1]

            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parseSells, meta={'IdList':FigureId,'SellList': priceSell}, dont_filter=True)

        else:
            pass

    except:
        dateSell_xpath = None

def parseSells (self, response):
    trsf_item = Item()
    IdList = str(response.meta['IdList'])
    SellList = response.meta['SellList']
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df.set_index('FigureId', inplace=True)
    df['FigureId'] = df['FigureId'].astype(str)
    df.loc[IdList,'Sell'] = SellList
    df.to_csv('Test' + file)
```

Comment: Instead of csv, use `sqllite` or any other database

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong this is a basic Type 2 SDC (slowly changing dimension) you need to first model your data appropriately, the best thing you should do is add an extract date so you can have some datetime variable to filter by.

Comment: Yes, sql could be a next step. For now I have csv. Then, the key data is the FigureId, which allow me to find the sold price.